# Running .exe files in tomcat server on unix

Tags: tomcat

I have a .exe file and I wish to run that file in apache tomcat server and its in UNIX. Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: exe files are normally for Windows. Are you sure it's compiled for your OS? If not, then it cannot be done.

Comment: that .exe file is compiled for UNIX.

Comment: Better find a consultant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). Install it on your machine and then you will be able to run any executable on your UNIX environment.